# Cannot get input value from the next form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get value of `pid` from the next input form using jQuery

But it does return `undefined`. I have tried many other tricks but not worked. So appreciate your suggestions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".replyit").click(function() {
    let pid = $(this).next(".pid").val();
    console.log('pid is', pid);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="dot.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">

    </form>
  </li>
```

Comment: Maybe a typo in rplyit instead of replyit?

Comment: @editors, please do not "fix" typos. Makes answer confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. next is for siblings, your link is not a sibling of the input field.
2. You likely want to cancel the click

Assuming Several sets of replies, this code will give you the next input from each

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".replyit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the href click
    const pid = $(this).closest(".treply") // OR this.parents("div"), which is not as specific
      .next() // ul
      .find(".pid").val();
    console.log('pid is', pid);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="dot.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">

    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, I had actually cut some divs. in fact the input field is some divs away from from the `Reply` button. Please check my updated question.

Comment: This one work: `$(this).parents("div").next().find(".pid").val();` Please modify your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: I would be careful with the less specific parents() than my `.closest(".containerClass")` - I have added it as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.next()` method will search for immediate siblings (on the same level) of the .replyit element. As .pid element is not a sibling to .replyit , the value returned is `undefined`.

To solve this, use `.parents()` and `.find()` methods instead of `.next()` to traverse through the DOM in the right way

```js
$(".replyit").click(function() {
  let pid = $(this).parents().next("ul").find(".pid").val();
  console.log(pid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <a class="replyit" href="#">Reply</a>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form class="likep" name="123" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="afewf">
      <input class="pid" type="hidden" name="pid" value="123">

    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```